# android studio render error with layout

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering, render

I get these errors all the time and I don't know why.
[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bmv4.png)

I changed nothing after the creation of the project but I don't see the basic app layout from the beginning.
[activity_main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nr3p.png)

PS: I am running the os manjaro on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to res => values => styles.xml and 
change

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

and make project agian